# Create a menu using pure css and HTML

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu structure like this :

```
<ul class"menu">
  <li>
    <a>item1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>subitem1</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem2</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem3</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem4</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>item2</a>
        <ul class="sub-ul-2">
          <li><a>subitem5</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem6</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem7</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My requirement is, when I hover on **item1** then subitem1,subitem2,subitem3,subitem4 only need to display and subitem5 - 8 no need to display.

When I hover on **item2**, then only subitem5 - 8 need to display. How can I achieve this by using css?

I have tried:

```
ul.menu ul{
 display: none;
}
ul.menu li:hover:first-child ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you'll need some jQuery in order to get the results you want.

Comment: You're missing a `=` in `class"menu"`. Also you might have forgotten to add `class="sub-ul-1"` to the second ul.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    item1
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">subitem1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">subitem2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">subitem3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">subitem4</a></li>
      <li>
        item2
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">subitem5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">subitem6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">subitem7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">subitem8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```css
.menu li > ul {
    display:none;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/E7Nc7/1/)

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? *(Without changing your html)*

CSS:

```
ul li ul {display:none;}
ul > li:hover ul{display:block;}
ul li ul > li > ul.sub-ul-2 {display:none;}
ul > li:hover ul > li:hover ul{display:block;}
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/q9n72/)**

---

Update: *(Without using any classes & cursos:pointer;)*

```
ul li ul {display:none;}
ul > li:hover ul{display:block;}
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li{display:none;}
ul > li:hover ul > li:hover ul li{display:block;}

li{cursor:pointer;}  /* For the hand (cursor) while hover over the li */
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9n72/4/)

---

Or the short css, after fixing the first ul from `<ul class"menu">` to `<ul class="menu">` *(By adding the **=** to it)*

```
.menu ul {display:none;}
.menu li:hover > ul{display:block;}
li{cursor:pointer;}
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/q9n72/5/)**

Answer (score 3):

I've put together a working and minimalistic [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5fy6/1/).

You hide all UL's inside `.menu`. Upon hovering any list-item, you reveal any direct descendant UL. I use `display: block;` and `display: none;` for the purpose of keeping it simple.

**CSS:**

```
/* Hide all UL's inside .menu */
.menu ul {
    display: none;
}

/* Show any UL which is a direct child of a hovered list-item */
.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z22kH/

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a>item1</a>
    <ul class="sub-ul-1">
      <li><a>subitem1</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem2</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem3</a></li>
      <li><a>subitem4</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>item2</a>
        <ul class="sub-ul-2">
          <li><a>subitem5</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem6</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem7</a></li>
          <li><a>subitem8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.menu li{
 display: none;
}
ul.menu > li{
 display: block;
}
ul.menu > li:hover > ul > li,
ul.menu ul > li:hover > ul > li{
  display:block;
}
```