# JS dropdown menu best practice

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement the following tiny drop down menu into my project.

Is there anything inherently wrong with my code? I attempted the `:hover` pseudo via CSS but was unsuccessful. Is there a better way to JS this thing?

```js
document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').style.visibility = 'visible'
})

document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').style.visibility = 'hidden'
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: darkslategray;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  display: inline-grid;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px;
}

img {
  margin: 3px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <img src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Blur-Backgrounds.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://akveo.com/blur-admin/assets/img/blur-bg-blurred.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/50000/velka/blurred-background-green.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/KyWYYX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS drop down menu hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863171/css-drop-down-menu-hover-effect)

Comment: Thanks, it is not a duplicate since I am wanting to see if the best solution is with JS

Comment: If you can do it with CSS, CSS is the better option

Comment: @lumio and how do I make it happen so that the choices stay while hovering? This was not answered in the other post

Comment: The trick is to set the pseudo class `:hover` to the parent (in your case `.dropdown`) and not on the `button`

Answer (score 3):

Although there are several posts describing [how to create a dropdown menu using just HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228456/create-a-menu-using-pure-css-and-html), I'll try to answer your question.

**tl;dr:** Use CSS over JS for better performance

### CSS or JS? Which one is better?

Basically whenever possible, use CSS over JS. There is a great [SO answer about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188419/better-or-worse-styling-with-javascript-vs-css).
Going further, CSS animations should be preferred over JS animations unless the animation should have some advanced effects. There is a good [google developers blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/css-vs-javascript) on this as well.

### How to create a dropdown menu

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551528/881032). Basically you need to set the `:hover` onto the parent element, that holds both the link and submenu.

```css
li img {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 150px;
}

/* hide submenus by setting the max-height to 0 */
ul > li > ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .75s ease;
}

/* set max-height to an approximate height it could have */
ul > li:hover > ul {
  max-height: 300px;
}

ul.submenu {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1em;
}

ul.submenu > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><img src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Blur-Backgrounds.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://akveo.com/blur-admin/assets/img/blur-bg-blurred.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/50000/velka/blurred-background-green.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you was facing the same issue that I was facing when I checked your codepen, since the .dropbtn are in the same level as .dropdown-content, the selector `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content` wont work since its searching for a child inside .dropbtn, so you have to use the sibling selector:

```
.dropbtn:hover ~ .dropdown-content{
  visibility: visible
}
```

(CSS animation its better than Javascript)

Also, a good practice in Javascript is to save the DOM element into an variable if you will use it multiple times, so you dont have to search for the DOM element again:

```
var dropBtnDOM = document.querySelector('.dropbtn');
var dropdownContentDom = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
dropBtnDOM.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    dropdownContentDom.style.visibility = 'visible'
})

dropBtnDOM.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    dropdownContentDom.style.visibility = 'hidden'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this. One step closer. Do you know how I make sure that the menu stays so that I can select one of the `img`'s ?

Comment: Just add  `.dropdown-content:hover` to have visibility with visible value. But for user experience, you should better go with javascript in order to add an delay to close, since the user may not go directly one element after another: Example: user hovers on the button, the dropdown is displayed but then goes outside of the button instead of going through the right side of the button where the dropdown and the button and then menu gets closed. (Moving the mouse like this https://image.prntscr.com/image/l1fcRpxFT1SSiKqK-BGOCw.png) That behavior is a little bit annoying

Comment: This does not work. I do appreciate the feedback for the user experience

Comment: You can also add a `transition: visibility 1s;` into the dropdown-content in order to add an delay through CSS. Here is the full CSS with both hover and transition solutions: https://jsfiddle.net/gbf49zqg/

Comment: @Helle have checked the jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn ~ .dropdown-content{
  visibility: visible
}
```