# Dropdown Menu in Bootswatch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

Is there a class specification in Bootswatch that displays a dropdown's menu items on hover rather than having the user click the menu? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a nav menu or a dropdown menu in a form? If nav check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863171/css-drop-down-menu-hover-effect

Comment: Someone just posted a link to an add-on but I’m not seeing their post any longer? Glitch? Looks like it’ll do the job, but I’ll look at Dan’s link job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Comment: should I remove this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below mentioned code using jquery for hover functionality.

Please refer this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/S8h5T/)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Regards D.

Comment: This is made using the Bootswatch theming...! I am sorry, but there is no particular class that you can use for it...you just need to toggle the ".open" class for hover effect.

Comment: Thanks, Devang. I’m guessing (not very familiar with jquery) that I can just add this code snippet to my html page? I’m using Visual Studio 2013 and WebForms if that makes in difference.

Comment: That is not a problem. You just need to make sure if jquery is already added in your project, and if not then you need to add this script `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head section of the page, and write the code in `$(document).ready(function () { \\code here });`

Comment: Nice solution. Two questions. (1) Does this interfere when browsing on a mobile device; (2) Wonder if this snippet could be placed inside a .js file and included as a resource or something like that?

Comment: (1)Unfortunately, hover effect is not supported in mobile browser, so for this, you need to write a click event for mobile browsers for the same effect and (2) Yes, you can write the code in external js file, and include as a resource in your project. In that .js file you need to add just `$( document ).ready(function() { //code here } );` and include the new resource file after including `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` file as described above

Comment: Thanks, Devang. Actually, what I meant was will this jquery snippet affect the toggle event in bootswatch? Added it as the correct answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for it, and yes, it can affect the toggle event in bootswatch. And for this i suggest you instead of using `$(".dropdown").hover(function () {`, you need to add a new selector targeting only navigation bar, that is `$(".nav .dropdown").hover(function () {` - Regards D.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.x has a dependency on jQuery 1.9 or greater.